# Hide hash in address bar when click on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want the URL in my address bar to stay "example.com/" instead of "example.com/#id" when clicking on a link class (.workLink). I've seen a lot of solutions to this problem, but I can't get anyone of them to work. This is what I'm working with right now:

```
$('.workLink').click(function () {
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/#.*/,''))
});
```

I've seen that the smoothScroll js-file uses `updateUrl: false` : Is this something I can implement?

Comment: Is the `.workLink` element the one with the href of `#id`? If so, you want prevention, not cure. Run preventDefault() on the event object in the handler and see if that does what you want

Comment: Yes. Did look through the simpleScroll js-file and found that they're using this to not update the URL : `var updateUrl = function ( anchor, url ) {
  if ( history.pushState && (url || url === 'true') ) {
   history.pushState( {
    pos: anchor.id
   }, '', window.location.pathname + anchor );
  }
 };` Is that something to can be implemented with preventDefault? @SmokeyPHP

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do this :

```
$('.workLink').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```